# Can't set colors of edges in igraph network

Tags: r, igraph

When I try to set the color of edges using the *edge.color* attribute, it doesn't work (I get default grey).  However when I put the same attribute in the plot command, it works!  What I am doing wrong?  (I am using  R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30) -- "Single Candle" on a linux box).  Other attributes such as *arrow.size* and *width* work fine for me, it is just the color that doesn't!

According to this Rpub tutorial for igraph, https://rpubs.com/kateto/netviz I should be able to do it both ways...

```
require(igraph)
data<-matrix(rexp(25, rate=.1), ncol=5)
gr<-graph.adjacency(data,mode="directed",weighted=T,diag=T)

# this gives gray default edges, WHY?
E(gr)$edge.color<-"blue"
plot(gr)

# this give blues edges:
plot(gr,edge.color="blue")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `color`, not `edge.color` (since it is an edge attribute this is already non-ambiguous).

```
E(gr)$color<-"blue"
plot(gr)
```

[image]

Comment: Ah thanks! so the Rpubs documentation is incorrect!!! They show E(net)$edge.color <- "gray80"  in their example... Thanks very much!

Comment: Yeah it might be outdated, not sure. They do seem to use `V(net)$color`. I just tried some variations since I knew it should work one way or another.

Comment: @AdrianTompkins I've reported it on [github](https://github.com/kateto/R-Network-Visualization-Workshop/issues/2).